# Unexpected encoding result for characters '&' and '\' from SQL ResultSet

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am unable to find the cause of decimal encode for few characters,

Actual value in SQL DB is `` special characters`~@#$%^&*()'";:,<.>/? ``

Db Value

[image]

But I am getting ResultSet value as `` special characters`~@#$%^38*()'";:,<.>47? ``, $ and / has been [decimal encoded](http://www.asciitable.com/) with 38 and 47 respectively.

Debug snapshot attached for reference.

[image]

How can I escape & and /? Why these characters are getting encoded?

Comment: try ASCII code? `Char(38)` for `&` and `CHAR(47)` for `/`

Comment: Any Idea, Why they are getting encoded? is there any other characters?

Comment: This encoding is most assuredly not performed by SQL Server. Some other code that's not being shown is responsible.

Comment: where did you get that result shown?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you, The SELECT query using to fetch the data  is encoding these characters in my case.

Comment: In Management Studio: `SELECT 'special characters\`~@#$%^&*()''";:,<.>/?'` -> `special characters\`~@#$%^&*()'";:,<.>/?` SQL Server isn't broken; either `resultset.getString` does this, or the assignment to `UIDocumentTitle` does this. I can't tell which one because I'm not familiar with the technology used.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.
Note I had to enter '' for '.

```
declare @sc varchar(100) = 'special characters`~@#$%^&*()''";:,<.>/?';
select @sc;
```